# Scala Parboiled 2 currying up some rules

Tags: scala, parsing, scala-macros, parboiled

I'd like to create some helper rules that take one rule and add some features to it. For example enforcing that string literals need to be quoted, or adding token position tracking to the token rules / ADT's.

I tried the following syntax (and quite a few permutations).

```
  def quoted[T](rl: Rule1[T]) = rule {
    '"' ~ rl ~ '"'
  }
```

It compiles fine but as soon as I wire it up --e.g.,

```
  def NodeObjPathEntry: Rule1[CNodeObjPathEntry] = rule {
    WhiteSpace ~ quoted(IdentifierStringUnwrapped) ~ ':' ~ (NodeObjArray | NodeObjObj) ~> CNodeObjPathEntry
  }
```

With the sub-rules :

```
def IdentifierStringUnwrapped: Rule1[String] = rule {
    clearSB() ~ IdentifierChars ~ push(sb.toString)   
}

 def IdentifierChars = rule {
    Alpha ~ appendSB() ~ zeroOrMore(AlphaNum ~ appendSB())
  }
```

I get `Illegal rule call: quoted[this.String](this.IdentifierStringUnwrapped)`

I could commit to an alternative approach: mix in the primitive token parsers, and then create the variants I need. But I really wanna figure out what is going on.

Comment: What is the type of `IdentifierStringUnwrapped`?

Comment: @wheaties added the sub-rules to the question body.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be the issue described under [Meta-rules](https://github.com/sirthias/parboiled2#meta-rules). The solution described would look like

```
val IdentifierStringUnwrapped: () => Rule1[String] = () => rule { ... }
// same for other rules you want to apply quoted to

def quoted[T](rl: () => Rule1[T]) = rule {
  '"' ~ rl() ~ '"'
}
```

No change in `NodeObjPathEntry`.

Unfortunately, this didn't work for *my* parser, so I may be misunderstanding something.